# Function with if statements

Tags: python, function, printing

I don't understand why this function doesn't print the text I want it to print, what could I change?

```
def shut_down(answer):
    if answer == "Yes" or "YES" or "yes":
        print "Shutting down..."
        return "Shutting down..."
    if answer == "No"or "NO" or "no":
        print "Shutdown aborted!"
        return "Shutdown aborted!"
    else: 
        print "Sorry, I didn't understand you."
        return "Sorry, I didn't understand you."



shut_down(yes)
```

Comment: It's always useful to add a tag for the language your question is about so that it gets seen by people familiar with that language. Please [edit] to add it. Thanks.

Comment: would be nice also to explain what is not working, what you are expecting and what  is the result you get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is not correct (the body of the `if` always executes):

```
if answer == "Yes" or "YES" or "yes":
```

Instead, write

```
if answer in {"Yes", "YES", "yes"}:
```

or

```
if answer.lower() == "yes":
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess the language is Python. The `or` operator operate between conditions, so you need to do

```
answer == "yes" OR answer == "YES"
```

etc ....

Your answer == "Yes" Or "YES" is always true because `"YES"` is considered as an true condition.

Answer (score 1):

```
if answer.lower() == 'yes':
```

That's how you should do it. Actually, do this: `if answer.lower() in ('yes', 'y'):` to make it more convenient for lazy people like myself.

Anyway, the proper way to check for a list of strings is this:

```
if answer in ('foo', 'bar', 'foobar'):
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to change it to this:

```
if answer == "Yes" or answer == "YES" or answer == "yes":
    print "Shutting down..."
    return "Shutting down..."
```

Or even tidier:

```
if answer in ["Yes", "YES", "yes"]:
```

or even moar tidier:

```
 if answer.lower() == "yes":
```

Answer (score -1):

You code probably has an error because you do not have the variable `yes` defined anywhere.

Define it, and then you *should* be good.

---

I am talking about the variable you are passing to your `shut_down` function